# What is the "kernel build", and where do I get it?

Tags: kernel, linux-kernel, compiling, network-interface

I am trying to compile [OpenOnload](http://www.openonload.org/) from Solarflare for my nic on a server that I'm building.  It is saying something about not having a kernel build.

```
root@server:/usr/src/openonload-201310-u2# ./scripts/onload_install
onload_install: Building OpenOnload.
mmakebuildtree: No kernel build at '/lib/modules/3.2.0-4-amd64/build'
onload_build: FAILED: mmakebuildtree --driver -d x86_64_linux-3.2.0-4-amd64
onload_install: ERROR: Build failed.  Not installing.
`
```

What is it talking about when it's saying there is supposed to be kernel build at  `/lib/modules/3.2.0-4-amd64/build`?  How would I get that file?

I'm using Debian 7 "Wheezy".

Comment: It's talking about the kernel development headers which are needed for compiling certain applications. The details on how to get them depend on your distribution. Please [edit] your question and add the distribution you are using.

Comment: @terdon Did just that.  I'm on Debian 7.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's talking about the kernel development headers which are needed for compiling certain applications. On Debian-based distributions, you can install them with this command:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-`uname -r`
```

If you're asked for that, you may also require the following:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essentials
```

That will install tools like `make` which might not be installed by default, I'm not sure.

Comment: also you can refer to "Appendix C: Build Dependencies" of the Onload User Guide for complete instructions. https://support.solarflare.com/index.php?option=com_cognidox&file=SF-104474-CD-16_Onload_User_Guide.pdf&task=download&format=raw&Itemid=11

Answer (score 0):

For those using Centos, this will work:

```
sudo yum install "kernel-devel-uname-r == $(uname -r)"
```

It will find the headers for the exact version of the kernel that you're using.